# FreeNAS iSCSI use - recommended percentage?

Tags: storage-area-network, iscsi, truenas

I have set up a FreeNAS system on a Dell R310 server with 4x4TB drives on a cross-flashed H200 controller in FreeNAS' own RAID10. I want to use that storage entirely for VM containers that run on another server. For this purpose, I am planning to set up an iSCSI share to be accessed by the other server via 10G ethernet.
In the FreeNAS documentation, it says it is not recommended to have a used space of more than 50% of the pool for iSCSI.

What do they mean: Can I use my whole RAID10 storage pool on FreeNAS to create an iSCSI share but that share should not exceed 50% usage? Or should the iSCSI share itself not comprise more than 50% of my available disk storage of the RAID10 array? I am a bit confused about the wording in the docs....